# Is there a way in SwiftUI to return a different view based on an optional binding having a value?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to show a view after fetching some data on my view model (where the data can be optional because the view model only fetches it on request).

Why is the following not possible / how should I go about it?

```
@Binding var someViewModel: SomeViewModel?

var body: some View {
    if let viewModel = self.someViewModel {
        return filledView(with: viewModel)
    }
    return emptyView()
}
```

The part not working here is an `if let` in the Swift UI view builder.

One solution would be to have a separate Bool that fires when data is loaded, or even an enum to identify when data is in and when it's not, but then the view code is full of optional value checking which isn't ideal.

E.g. I want to avoid doing something like:

```
Image(systemName: someViewModel?.icon.symbol() ?? "plus_sign")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .padding()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You could use map. It will unwrap the optional if it has some value or ignore it altogether:

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        someViewModel.map { FilledView(with: $0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems there's more than one option. Good stuff :)

Comment: Group is much more efficient than AnyView. AnyView prevents the compiler from optimizing out unnecessary layers. If you know what views are possible at compile-time you should always use Group. You should only use AnyView when the list of possible Views is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Rob!

Comment: I see that from the docs here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map applying map function to an optional yields another optional. So that must mean we are returning an optional view inside the Group. How does that work?

Answer (score 3):

Just found another option, we could wrap both the empty and filled view function returns in an `AnyView` and the problems disappear as well.

Example of the empty would then become:

```
func emptyView() -> AnyView {
        return AnyView(Text(""))
    }
```

And example of the filled view becomes:

```
func filledView(for viewModel: SomeViewModel) -> AnyView {
    return AnyView(VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Image(systemName: viewModel.icon.symbol())
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an easy workaround. Are there downsides to AnyView?

Comment: Yeah it works but might have issue with the Preview. Error such as `cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyView' to return type 'some View'
`